# SQL query containing IP address works as normal query but not as prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

**see bottom for the code that worked**

I have a page that checks the last time a user pressed a button from the user's current IP address. The code looks like this:

```
$lastPressQuery = "SELECT MAX(tstamp) AS 'last_press' FROM presses WHERE ip = $ipNum";
$lastPressResult = mysqli_query($conn, $lastPressQuery);
$lastPressRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lastPressResult);
```

(`$ipNum` is converted using ip2long)

This code works as intended. However, in line with best practices, I would like to change this to a prepared statement. This is the code I wrote for the prepared statement:

```
$lastPressQuery = $conn -> prepare("SELECT MAX(tstamp) AS 'last_press' FROM presses WHERE ip = ?");
$lastPressQuery -> bind_param("i", $ipNum);
$lastPressResult = $lastPressQuery -> execute();
$lastPressRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lastPressResult);
```

This does not work. `execute()` returns false.

I have tried leaving the IP address as a string, leaving `$ip` as a string and putting apostrophes around it or the question mark, checking `ipNum` for mistakes, and entering the query it should create directly into SQL (which works). A later prepared statement to `INSERT` data works fine. What is causing this prepared statement to fail?

**EDIT:** I finally got this to work. The code that succeeded is:

```
$lastPressQuery = $conn -> prepare("SELECT MAX(tstamp) AS 'last_press' FROM presses WHERE ip = ?");
$lastPressQuery -> bind_param("i", $ipNum);
$lastPressQuery -> execute();
$lastPressResult = $lastPressQuery -> get_result();
```

Comment: you know IP != person. one person can use many IP's and one IP can be thousands of different people.

Comment: I'm aware, but until everything I have works, I'm not concerned with robustly distinguishing between people.

Comment: Make sure [mysqli raises exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1422451). What is `gettype($ipNum)`?

Comment: `$ipNum` is an integer

Comment: What exactly is `$ipNum`? Could you give an example? Why is it an integer?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that succeeded is:

```
$lastPressQuery = $conn -> prepare("SELECT MAX(tstamp) AS 'last_press' FROM presses WHERE ip = ?");
$lastPressQuery -> bind_param("i", $ipNum);
$lastPressQuery -> execute();
$lastPressResult = $lastPressQuery -> get_result();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the prepared statement object, not the result, try

```
$lastPressResult = $lastPressResult -> execute();
$lastPressRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lastPressResult);
```

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I've updated my code to match, but `execute()` still returns false when I run this.

Comment: Paste your CREATE TABLE statement, please, maybe the field is not wide enough or is unsigned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "field is not wide enough or is unsigned" but I do know that the same query works with mysqli_query() and no preparation.

EDIT: I thought earlier that execute was returning false, `echo $lastPressResult;` returns true (or rather, 1).